# use custom shipping method to calculate shipping price in another section of the marketplace (rma)

Tags: magento2, shipping, custom, development, rma

I have a problem, I am creating a custom module of rma, the module must allow to calculate the price of the shipment. Additionally I have a custom shipping module that works correctly in the purchase process but I have to calculate shipping prices in the rma module(for return product), I am trying to do this by calling a function of the shipping module but it does not execute.

The Shipping module:

app/code/xxxx/xxxx/model/carrier/shipping.php

```
class Shipping extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{
    #...rest of class methods
    
    #function to calculate rates
     public function getShippingPrice($origenRegion,$origenCiudad, $destinoRegion, $destinoCiudad, $peso)
     {
        # ...rest of function
        $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($tasa);
                
        return $shippingPrice;
     }
    
     public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
     {
        #...
     }
    
}
```

The shipping rates works fine, but when I try to use the getShippingPrice function in another section (an observer) it does not get executed.

```
class RmaSuccess implements ObserverInterface
{
     protected $_ShippingModel;
     public function __construct(\xxxx\xxxx\Model\Carrier\Shipping $ShippingModel){

     $this->_ShippingModel = $ShippingModel;
     }

      public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer ) { 
         #....
         CostOfRefound = $this->_ShippingModel->getShippingPrice($shippingAdressOrigin->getRegion(),
                    $shippingAdressOrigin->getCity(), $SellerRegion, $SellerCiudad,($PesoTotalSeller[$key])/1000);
         #....the function does not run

      }
}
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change this section as below

From:

```
CostOfRefound = $this->_ShippingHelper->getShippingPrice($shippingAdressOrigin->getRegion(),
                    $shippingAdressOrigin->getCity(), $SellerRegion, $SellerCiudad,($PesoTotalSeller[$key])/1000);
```

To:

```
CostOfRefound = $this->_ShippingModel->getShippingPrice($shippingAdressOrigin->getRegion(),
                    $shippingAdressOrigin->getCity(), $SellerRegion, $SellerCiudad,($PesoTotalSeller[$key])/1000);
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, but that is not the case, I modified that part to place the question but in the original code they match, I already edited the question